# Is it possible that time complexity of any algorithm decrease as the input size increase, any example

Tags: performance, algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o

I just read in Cormen's algorithm book that big-O and big-omega do not follow the trichotomy property. That means for two functions, `f(n)` and `g(n)`, it may be the case that neither `f(n) = O(g(n))` nor `f(n) = Omega(g(n))` holds. In example they argue that if function is `n^(1+sin n)` than it is possible.

While it is correct is it possible in a real world algorithm to have a run time of something like `sin n`. Since it would sometimes decrease, with the increase of input size. Does anybody knows any such algorithm or can give a small code snippet which does this.

Thanks for the answers, so in that case is it correct to assume that Given a problem P with size n, if it can not be solved in O(f(n)) time by any known algorithm, then the lower bound of P is Omega(f(n)).

Comment: It's easy to construct contrived examples of functions that have odd runtimes like this, but to the best of my knowledge no functions have asymptotic runtimes that decrease as the input gets larger.

Comment: Yeah as templatetypedef says usually they are contrived examples and there are contrived examples for functions that have runtimes that decrease but they are not really of use to anyone except that it can be done :\

Comment: Might be better on cstheory.SE?

Comment: they just describe the mathematical properties of those notations. you don't necessarily use them for algorithmic complexity analysis.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, so in that case is it correct to assume that Given a problem P with size n, if it can not be solved in O(f(n)) time by any known algorithm, then the lower bound of P is Omega(f(n)).

Comment: Some function that increases and decreases like sin(x) may be possible with a contrived example. An algorithm could not have a decreasing function as its complexity however. As you increase the input, the number of steps in the algorithm will decrease, but you cannot reduce them below 0. So eventually it will be some constant number, and the algorithm must have constant complexity.

Comment: Other people suggest good functions in their sample, but I don't know why you think `sin(x)` is not a real algorithmic function, sure you use it sometimes in your code, and it's good to see implementation behind it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have difficulties conceiving a meaningful problem with decreasing complexity. A "meaningful" problem will need to read or touch parts of all of its input. Unless the input is encoded in a very inefficient way, processing it should take an increasing amount of time.

It could be increasing toward a constant, though.

Comment: 'A "meaningful" problem will need to read or touch parts of all of its input'. Binary search only has to read a logarithmic amount of its input on average.

Answer (score 16):

The Boyer-Moore string search algorithm gets faster when the string searched *for* gets longer.  Of course, the limiting factor is most often rather the length of the string searched *in*.

Answer (score 5):

The average running time of SAT for randomly-generated 3CNF clauses eventually goes down as the ratio of clauses to variables increases. The intuition is that when there are very many clauses relative to the number of variables, it is more likely that the formula is "obviously" unsatisfiable; that is, typical SAT-solving algorithms (a step or two better than exhaustive search, but simple enough to cover in an undergrad logic course) quickly reach contradictions and stop.

Of course, those are experimental observations for some notion of "random" 3CNF formulas. I'm not sure what people have proven about it.

Comment: Interesting answer! Do you include the time needed to parse the clauses in the running time? From a theoretical perspective, it's important because even if the time taken for finding contradictions goes down, the time needed for parsing should be the dominating cost beyond a certain point.

Comment: Right, generating (or parsing) the formula takes time linear in the number of clauses (times the log of the number of variables, if you really want to be precise).

Answer (score 3):

Use any inverse function.

```
f(x) -> 1 / x
f(x) -> 1 / x²
f(x) -> 1 / log(x)
```

As the input `x` grows, the resulting value will get smaller. It's fairly straightforward to relate a smaller value to lesser number of steps in the algorithm. Just use a counter in a loop to move towards that number.

Here's a simple algorithm.

```
function(x) {
    step = 0.001
    y = 1 / x;
    for (i = 0; i < y; i += step) { /* do something awesome here */ }
}
```

Comment: Really don't understand, how to get any of the f(x) you have mentioned as the runtime of an algorithm ?

Comment: I've added a simple function that correlates the input value, and the number of steps the algorithm takes to complete.

Comment: These aren't O(1/x) though. They are O(1). You will inevitably run in to discreteness problems.

Comment: Agree with Jems. We always talk about asymptotic complexity, and all of these approach zero in the limit and are thus O(1).

Comment: @Jems, @phkahler - When we're using asymptotic time complexity, we're not interested in the convergent value. Otherwise all algorithms will simply be `O(∞)` or `O(1)`. Because as `n` converges to `∞`, the number of steps any algorithm that depends on `n` such as `O(n)` or `O(n³)` takes will simply converge to `∞`. So it's perfectly fine to say that the complexity of the above algorithm is `O(1/n)`. As far as discreetness is concerned, one can always pick an appropriate stepping value instead of using a fixed one such as `0.001`.

Comment: @Anurag If your algorithm always runs at least one step, then it is already Omega(1).  The alternative is a zero-step algorithm.

Comment: @Anurag: What is the underlying computation model you are assuming? Computing 1/x is not constant-time, I expect it's at least O(ln x).

Comment: @Anurag, O(\inf) vs O(n): People are interested in the representation that provides most information. O(1/n) doesn't say more than O(1), but O(n) says more than O(\inf).

Comment: @han - I don't quite follow. If an algorithm runs at least one step, which can be said of most algorithms out there for a non-zero input, then they're not automatically O(1).

Comment: @Joh - the underlying computation model is simply that computing 1/x is going to be far less intensive than that loop. So we ignore it. Since this is a contrived example, we can control how to make that loop more intensive.

Comment: @Joh - That's a good point you just brought up. People are interested in the representation that gives the most information. But then it becomes dependent on the observer. While `O(1/n)` may speak very little to you about the algorithm, it may make a huge difference to a scientist whose domain only consists of extremely small values between `0` and `1`. Values so small that it may take the fastest computers of today several years to complete that loop. Should they just go with `O(1)` instead because it speaks a lot more about the algorithm generically speaking?

Comment: @Anurag, O(1/n) doesn't tell you anything about how "small" the limit is, as we leave the constant factor out. Regarding my other comment about the complexity of 1/x versus the complexity of the loop, you have explicitly designed your algorithm so that the loop executes faster as x grows, and there is a point where you cannot neglect the division anymore. I know it "feels" like 1/x takes constant time, but that's not true if your numeric type has variable size, which it should for the purpose of complexity analysis.

Comment: @Anurag Omega() is a lower bound on a function, just like O() is an upper bound.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: O(n) considers the worst case scenario. Here your worst case scenario occurs at n=1. Therefore it will run for O(1000) which is essentially O(1)

Comment: @AkshayLAradhya You are correct about Oh. But what should be the Omega asymptote then?

Comment: @AkshayLAradhya Why is the worst case n = 1 and not n = 0.000000001. Are you assuming the input set must be integral?

Comment: @Anurag Yeah I assumed x would be an integer